# llvm headers do not compile under msvc 2013

Tags: c++, visual-c++, llvm, header-files

When trying to use llvm to code a backend for the compiler I am creating msvc gives me multiple errors in multiple header files.

For Example in a variety of .def files included in llvm the compiler outputs that there is an unknown character ('@'/0x40). Also it outputs that there is a Large Number of missing semicolons as well as redefinitions of LLVM_ENUM_TARGETS and missing type specifiers. Most of the header files where these errors occur state that they should not be changed and are generated at configuration time.

Offending files:

```
"targets.def"  
"asmprinters.def"  
"asmparsers.def"  
"dissassemblers.def"  
"target.h"
```

If someone could give a suggestion on what I appear to have missed and what I need to do to fix it please feel free.

Comment: sounds like some files needed to be configured before building? I have never built llvm before but I know '@' is used in cmake for configuring.

Comment: It appears that the cmake configuring stage is failing at parts due to the fact that msvc is missing some posix header files sub as "dirent.h" and quite a few others